# Bulk Search/replacing of filenames using python

Tags: list, python-2.7, xlrd

I have:

1. An excel file as A1:B2.
2. A folder with 200 jpeg files.

I'm trying to search the filename in the folder with the value in `Column A` and replace it with the value in `Column B` if found without changing the extensions of the files in the folder.

Here am stuck using various skiddies to do this but failed. Here's my code:

```
import os
import xlrd
path = r'c:\users\c_thv\desktop\x.xls'
#collect the files in fexceler
path1 = r'c:\users\c_thv\desktop'
data = []
for name in os.listdir(path1):
  if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path1, name)):
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(name)
     if fileExtension == '.py':
       data.append(fileName)
#print data
#collect the filenames for changing
book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
cell = sheet.cell(0,0)
cells = sheet.row_slice(rowx=0,start_colx=0,end_colx=2)
excel = []
#collect the workable data in an list
for cell in cells:
  excel.append(cell) 
#print excel
#compare list for matches
for i,j in enumerate(excel):
  if j in data[:]:
    os.rename(excel[i],data[i])
```

Comment: How did it fail? What (didn't) happen?

Comment: @TimCastelijns :- Nothing Changes. .No Effect. . I think something goes wrong in comparison of two things(lists). I'm not quite sure about the **rename** line. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Can i Use Dictionaries. .?
Any ways to create dicts fro excel. .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `print "Match found"` after `if j in data[:]:` just to check if the condition is ever met. My guess is there will be no match because the list `data` is full on python filemanes (`if fileExtension == '.py'`) and you are looking for jpeg files in the `excel` list.
Besides, `old` is not defined.

EDIT:

If I understand correctly, this will may help:

```
import os, xlrd

path = 'c:/users/c_thv/desktop' #path to jpg files
path1 = 'c:/users/c_thv/desktop/x.xls'

data =[] #list of jpg filenames in folder

#lets create a filenames list without the jpg extension
for name in os.listdir(path):
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(name)
    if fileExtension =='.jpg':
        data.append(fileName)


#lets create a list of old filenames in the excel column a

book = xlrd.open_workbook(path1)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
oldNames =[]
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    oldNames.append(sheet.cell_value(row,0))


#lets create a list with the new names in column b
newNames =[]
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    newNames.append(sheet.cell_value(row,1))


#now create a dictionary with the old name in a and the corresponding new name in b

fileNames = dict(zip(oldNames,newNames))

print fileNames

#lastly rename your jpg files

for f in data:
    if f in fileNames.keys():
        os.rename(path+'/'+f+'.jpg', path+'/'+fileNames[f]+'.jpg')
```

Comment: Blank list returns. . And sorry, `old` should be replaced `excel`. . edited.
if the file extension is '.py' append the respective filename.
it shall be replaced as `data.append(glob.glob('*.py'))`. . right. .?
Please review it. .